# Does EOS support signing a string?

Tags: signing

Ethereum has `web3.eth.personal.sign` that supports signing any string.

Obviously EOS supports signing transactions, but I don't see any support for signing a string.

Have I missed this or does EOS not support this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I assume that you are looking for a possibility in javascript?

Eosjs doesn't support signing a string but eosjs-ecc does.

See here:

- [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc)
- [eosjs-ecc sign](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc#sign)

Comment: >Based on your question I assume that you are looking for a possibility in javascript?

Yes.

Thanks for your response. I guess the question then is are there any EOS metamask style wallets that support signing?

Answer (score 0):

There are many Wallets out there that are supporting ***Arbitrary Signatures*** (with some limitations). From what I know there's no Metamask-Style Wallet (Browser-Extension) and only Desktop-Wallets which support them.

Take a look here: [Scatter-Arbitrary-Signtaure](https://get-scatter.com/developers/api/requestarbitrarysignature)

here: [Scatter-Arbitrary-Signature-Limitations](https://github.com/GetScatter/scatter-js/issues/155)

and here: [Lynx-Arbitrary-Signature](https://developers.lynxwallet.io/sdk)

Comment: Thanks. I really need a browser extension wallet that supports this. It seems odd that one doesn't exist.